# Rendering component inside Route in React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make to render children in father component with React Router Dom `v6.2.2`, that's how I tried to make it but browser shows nothing eventually:

```
const MainLayout = props => {
    return (
        <div className='main-layout'>
            <Header />
            <div className='main'>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
            <MainLayout>
              <Homepage />
            </MainLayout>
          )} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Hi, did the below answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `element` property of `Route` to render your component since you are using React Router Dom `v6`, `component` and `render` are for anterior versions, or simply wrap it inside `Route`:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <MainLayout>
              <Homepage />
            </MainLayout>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Homepage />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and Add a `Outlet` component inside MainLayout Component

```
const MainLayout = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-layout">
        <Header />
        <div className="main">{props.children}</div>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}
```